# How to export a class in a PowerShell v5 module

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I've got a module setup to be like a library for a few other scripts. I can't figure out how to get a class declaration into the script scope calling [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module). I tried to arrange `Export-Module` with a `-class` argument, like the `-function`, but there isn't a `-class` available. Do I just have to declare the class in every script?

The setup:

- holidays.psm1 in ~\documents\windows\powershell\modules\holidays\
- active script calls `import-module holidays`
- there is another function in holidays.psm1 that returns a class object correctly, but I don't know how to create new members of the class from the active script after importing

Here is what the class looks like:

```
Class data_block
{
    $array
    $rows
    $cols
    data_block($a, $r, $c)
    {
        $this.array = $a
        $this.rows = $r
        $this.cols = $c
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Import-Module holidays -verbose` list your `data_block`?

Comment: There is just 1 other function in there & it's all that shows up:                `PS ~> import-module holidays -verbose     
VERBOSE: Importing function 'get-holidays'.`

Comment: You can. Consider changing the accepted reply to :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38701492/2502814

Comment: Does `Export-Module` actually exist (not a rhetorical question)? Is it [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/MsftPowerShell/powershell-using-statement) and [here](https://arcanecode.com/2016/04/05/accessing-a-powershell-class-defined-in-a-module-from-outside-a-module/), you can use classes defined in your module by doing the following in PowerShell 5:

```
using module holidays
```

Comment: `using` is amazingly frustrating.  I have found it basically unusable except for the most trivial circumstances.  It turns out though, that `.NewBoundScriptBlock()` works fine to export instances of a class.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40441684/1404637).

Comment: Danger! Danger!  I've beaten my head against the wall countless times on this.  Apparently not all 5.0's are the same in this regard.  This DOES NOT WORK in 5.0.10514.6 (check using (Get-Host).Version).  Update your copy of WinRM 5.0 and it will work (5.0.10586.117 works)!

Comment: The second link, which states that you can make a function that creates instances of you class and call it to get objects of the class is a work around.

Answer (score 31):

*PSA: There is a known issue that keeps old copies of classes in memory.  It makes working with classes really confusing if you don't know about it.  You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42878789/1404637).*

---

### `using` is Prone to Pitfalls

The `using` keyword is prone to various pitfalls as follows:

- The `using` statement does not work for modules not in `PSModulePath` unless you specify the module's full path in the `using` statement.  This is rather surprising because although a module is available via `Get-Module` the `using` statement may not work depending on how the module was loaded.
- The `using` statement can only be used at the very beginning of a "script".  No combination of `[scriptblock]::Create()` or `New-Module` seems overcome this.  A string passed to `Invoke-Expression` seems to act as a sort of standalone script; a `using` statement at the beginning of such a string sort of works.  That is, `Invoke-Expression "using module $path"` can succeed but the scope into which the contents of the module are made available seems rather inscrutable.  For example, if `Invoke-Expression "using module $path"` is used inside a Pester scriptblock, the classes inside the module are not available from the same Pester scriptblock.

The above statements are based on [this set of tests](https://github.com/alx9r/ToolFoundations/blob/ee939846aa88d583fc32a173a20e8ae5a64a5faa/EnvironmentTests/usingModuleTests.ps1).

### `ScriptsToProcess` Prevents Access to Private Module Functions

Defining a class in a script referred to by the module manifest's `ScriptsToProcess` seems at first glance to export the class from the module.  However, instead of exporting the class, it ["creates the class in the global SessionState instead of the module's, so it...can't access private functions"](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5942#issuecomment-364804062).  As far as I can tell, using `ScriptsToProcess` is like defining the class outside the module in the following manner:

```
#  this is like defining c in class.ps1 and referring to it in ScriptsToProcess
class c {
    [string] priv () { return priv }
    [string] pub  () { return pub  }
}

# this is like defining priv and pub in module.psm1 and referring to it in RootModule
New-Module {
    function priv { 'private function' }
    function pub  { 'public function' }
    Export-ModuleMember 'pub'
} | Import-Module

[c]::new().pub()  # succeeds
[c]::new().priv() # fails
```

Invoking this results in

```
public function
priv : The term 'priv' is not recognized ...
+         [string] priv () { return priv } ...
```

The module function `priv` is inaccessible from the class even though `priv` is called from a class that was defined when that module was imported.  This might be what you want, but I haven't found a use for it because I have found that class methods usually need access to some function in the module that I want to keep private.

### `.NewBoundScriptBlock()` Seems to Work Reliably

Invoking a scriptblock bound to the module containing the class seems to work reliably to export instances of a class and does not suffer from the pitfalls that `using` does.  Consider this module which contains a class and has been imported:

```
New-Module 'ModuleName' { class c {$p = 'some value'} } |
    Import-Module
```

Invoking `[c]::new()` inside a scriptblock bound to the module produces an object of type `[c]`:

```
PS C:\> $c = & (Get-Module 'ModuleName').NewBoundScriptBlock({[c]::new()})
PS C:\> $c.p
some value
```

### Idiomatic Alternative to `.NewBoundScriptBlock()`

It seems that there is a shorter, idiomatic alternative to `.NewBoundScriptBlock()`.  The following two lines each invoke the scriptblock in the session state of the module output by `Get-Module`:

```
& (Get-Module 'ModuleName').NewBoundScriptBlock({[c]::new()})
& (Get-Module 'ModuleName') {[c]::new()}}
```

The latter has the advantage that it will yield flow of control to the pipeline mid-scriptblock when an object is written to the pipeline.  `.NewBoundScriptBlock()` on the other hand collects all objects written to the pipeline and only yields once execution of the entire scriptblock has completed.

Comment: Good to know, though while `using module` requires a _literal_ path (no variables allowed), it can also be a _relative_ path. Also, it makes sense not to default to whatever module by that name _happens to be loaded_.

Comment: I don't know if and when something changed, but loading modules from directories in `$env:PSModulePath` by _name only_ with `using module` does seem to work, even in the WinPS v5.1 version that comes with W11 22H2.

Comment: I think your W11 observation matches what the answer from 2016 claims.  As I read this, the answer claims modules that are not in `PSModulePath` (like those loaded using the form [`Import-Module -Name c:\ps-test\modules\test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1) do not load with the `using` statement.  I'm pretty sure `using` modules in `PSModulePath` by name has more-or-less worked in all versions that implemented `using`.

Answer (score 19):

I found a way to load the classes without the need of "using module".
In your MyModule.psd1 file use the line:

```
ScriptsToProcess = @('Class.ps1')
```

And then put your classes in the Class.ps1 file:

```
class MyClass {}
```

Update: Although you don't have to use "using module MyModule" with this method you still have to either:

- Run "using module MyModule"
- Or run "Import-Module MyModule"
- Or call any function in your module (so it will auto import your module on the way)

Update2: This will load the Class to the current scope so if you import the Module from within a function for example the Class will not be accessible outside of the function. Sadly the only reliable method I see is to write your Class in C# and load it with `Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition 'MyClass...'`.

Comment: This is a great way to expose public classes that are stored in individual ps1s or a subfolder of your module. Can be used as a with a wild card `ScriptsToProcess = @('publicClasses\*.ps1')`

Comment: It doesn't work: `Import-Module : The member 'ScriptsToProcess' in the module manifest is not valid: The path cannot be processed because it
resolved to more than one file; only one file at a time can be processed.. Verify that a valid value is specified for this field
in the 'C:\Stash\MyModule\MyModule.psd1' file.`

Comment: [`ScriptsToProcess` "specifies script (.ps1) files that run in the caller's session state"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-6) and it ["creates the class in the global SessionState instead of the module's, so it gets exported by default and can't access private functions"](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5942#issuecomment-364804062). The class is not defined in the module at all.  Strictly-speaking, that's different from the original question of "how to export a class from a module".

Answer (score 8):

The [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-6) statement is the way to go if it works for you. Otherwise this seems to work as well.

#### File *testclass.psm1*

Use a function to deliver the class

```
class abc{
    $testprop = 'It Worked!'
    [int]testMethod($num){return $num * 5}
}

function new-abc(){
    return [abc]::new()
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function new-abc
```

#### File *someScript.ps1*

```
Import-Module path\to\testclass.psm1
$testclass = new-abc
$testclass.testProp        # Returns 'It Worked!'
$testclass.testMethod(500) # Returns 2500


$testclass | gm


Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
testMethod  Method     int testMethod(System.Object num)
ToString    Method     string ToString()
testprop    Property   System.Object testprop {get;set;}
```

Comment: What don't you like about it?

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is about the best way I've seen to modularize things in the bounds of an object and access it from a module.  It may not isolate the scope for privatizing things in the class, but it's about the best we can do given some of the limitations of PS.

Comment: I like this way to go, it's PS idiomatic and let me avoid using _using module_.

Answer (score 5):

You pretty much cannot. According to `about_Classes` help:

> **Class keyword**
>
> Defines a new class. This is a true .NET Framework type. Class members are public, but only public within the module scope. You can't refer to the type name as a string (for example, New-Object doesn't work), and in this release, you can't use a type literal (for example, [MyClass]) outside the script/module file in which the class is defined.

This means, if you want to get yourself a `data_block` instance or use functions that operate those classes, make a function, say, `New-DataBlock` and make it return a new `data_block` instance, which you can then use to get class methods and properties (likely including static ones).

Comment: "You pretty much cannot": This used to be true, but in Powershell 5 you now can. Lars Tuijens' answer give the extra command to add after your Import-module.
 "using statement enables in PowerShell is the ability to import PowerShell Classes from PowerShell modules!"

Comment: It seems like this was never quite accurate as it looks like you could always [`& (Get-Module ModuleName).NewBoundScriptBlock({[data_block]::new()]}` to export an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40441684/1404637) even before `using` was available.

Comment: Seconding that this hasn't been true since v5.1 at least: ```Classes that you want to be available to users outside of the module should be defined in the root module.``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-5.1#importing-classes-from-a-powershell-module

Answer (score 5):

This certainly does not work as expected. 
The idea in PowerShell 5 is that you can define your class in a separate file with a .psm1 extension. 
Then you can load the definition with the command (e.g.):

```
using module C:\classes\whatever\path\to\file.psm1
```

This must be the first line in your script (after comments).

What causes so much pain is that even if the class definitions are called from a script, the modules are loaded for the entire session. You can see this by running:

```
Get-Module
```

You will see the name of the file you loaded. No matter if you run the script again, it will **not** reload the class definitions! (It won't even read the psm1 file.) This causes much gnashing of teeth.

Sometimes - *sometimes* - you can run this command before running the script, which will reload the module with refreshed class definitions:

```
Remove-Module  file
```

where file is the name without path or extension. However, to save your sanity I recommend restarting the PowerShell session. This is obviously cumbersome; Microsoft needs to clean this up somehow.

Comment: I've created this issue to address the problem of the `using module` statement not reloading the module after changes have been made to it. Please go thumbs up it to up-vote it. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654

Comment: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/35237182--using-module-statement-does-not-reload-module-af
@deadlydog, I believe it was you who added this User Voice, as well.

Comment: You should be able to reload a module with `Import-Module MyModule -Force`. Not perfect, but still a viable workaround.

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered multiple issues regarding PowerShell classes in v5 as well.

I've decided to use the following workaround for now, as this is perfectly compatible with .NET and PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition @"
namespace My.Custom.Namespace {
    public class Example
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public System.Management.Automation.PSCredential Credential { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
"@
```

The benefit is that you don't need a custom assembly to add a type definition. You can add the class definition inline in your PowerShell scripts or modules.

The only downside is that you will need to create a new runtime to reload the class definition after is has been loaded for the first time (just like loading assemblies in a C#/.NET domain).

Answer (score 1):

The way I've worked around this problem is to move your custom class definition into an empty .ps1 file with the same name (like you would in Java/C#), and then load it into both the module definition and your dependent code by dot sourcing.  I know this isn't great, but to me it's better than having to maintain multiple definitions of the same class across multiple files...

Answer (score 1):

To update class definitions while developing, select the code for the class and press <kbd>F8</kbd> to run the selected code. It is not as clean as the `-Force` option on the `Import-Module` command.

Seeing as `using Module` doesn't have that option and [`Remove-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-module) is sporadic at best, this is the best way I have found to develop a class and see the results without having to close down the [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) and start it up again.

Answer (score 0):

A surprising & cumbersome limitation of `using module` appears to be that any classes to expose outside of a module MUST be in the module's psm1 file itself.

**A class definition to expose outside the module cannot be 'dotsourced' into the psm1 file from a separate ps1 file in the module**

...this is as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2#importing-classes-from-a-powershell-module) since v5.1 (to at least 7.2):

> The using module statement imports classes from the root module
> (ModuleToProcess) of a script module or binary module. It does not
> consistently import classes defined in nested modules or classes
> defined in scripts that are dot-sourced into the module. **Classes that
> you want to be available to users outside of the module should be
> defined in the root module**.

So therefore, it seems the simplest options (as discussed in other answers) are:

1. If you only need to reference class **instances** outside of its defining module, create public functions to return class instances:

   `function Get-MyModulesClass { [MyModuleClass]::New() }`
2. To reference a class **type** outside of the module (eg specifing a function argument's type), the class must have been defined directly in the psm1 file of the module, and this psm1 file must have been included in your external script via `using module` (eg `using module <relativePathToModulePsm1File>`).

*...and of course what doesn't help when figuring all this out is that [classes don't reload](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654) so you need start a new powershell session every time you make a change to the classes.*

## Example Module

### /MyLibaryModule/MyPrivateClass.ps1:

```
class MyPrivateClass { 
    [void] Test(){ Write-Host "Accessed private class methods!"}
}
```

### /MyLibaryModule/MyLibraryModule.psm1

```
class MyPublicClass {} # Exposed classes MUST be defined in this file

. $PSScriptRoot\MyPrivateClass.ps1
function Get-MyPrivateClassInstance { [MyPrivateClass]::new()}
```

### /ExampleScript.ps1

```
using module .\MyLibraryModule\MyLibraryModule.psm1 

[MyPublicClass]$myVar1 # Works 

[MyPrivateClass]$myVar2  # Errors 

Import-Module .\MyLibraryModule\MyLibraryModule.psm1 
$object = Get-MyPrivateClassInstance
$object.GetType().Name
$object.Test()  # works
```

### Output

```
InvalidOperation: 
Line |
   5 |  [MyPrivateClass]$myVar2  # Errors
     |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [MyPrivateClass].
MyPrivateClass
Accessed private class methods!
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and created [this sample repo](https://github.com/deadlydog/PowerShell.Experiment.ClassInModule) and setup various tests and found the following.

### Using PowerShell classes

The only way to be able to reference the class type by name outside of the module (e.g. `[data_block]::new()`) is:

1. The class must be defined directly in the psm1 file; it cannot be dot-sourced in.
2. The module must be imported with `using module`.

If you use dot-sourcing or `Import-Module`, everything within the module itself can reference the class name fine, but if something outside of the module references the class name it will get a `Unable to find type [data_block]` error.

### Using C# classes

Everything just works when using C# classes. You can define them in separate files and dot-source them into the .psm1 file, and they will be fully available within the module and to consumers of the module whether they use `Import-Module` or `using module`.

For more details, [check out this blog post](https://blog.danskingdom.com/How-and-where-to-properly-define-classes-and-enums-in-your-PowerShell-modules/).

---

To answer your specific question:

> I can't figure out how to get a class declaration into the script scope calling Import-Module

This is not possible. You need to either convert your PowerShell class into a C# class, or else use `using module` ([see the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using#module-syntax)) to import the module into your script instead of `Import-Module`.

This is what your sample class might look like as a C# class defined in PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -Language CSharp -TypeDefinition @"
  public class data_block
  {
    public int[] array { get; set; }
    public int rows { get; set; }
    public int cols { get; set; }

    data_block(int[] a, int r, int c)
    {
        this.array = a
        this.rows = r
        this.cols = c
    }
  }
"@
```