# Use a custom class defined in a different file as type in Powershell

Tags: powershell, types, casting

I want to use a custom class I declared in a different file as a type:

emailhelper.ps1

```
class EmailInfo
{
    [string]$subject;
    [string]$body;
    [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$distributionList;
}
```

myfile.ps1

```
."$PSScriptRoot\.\emailhelper.ps1"

class MyClass
{
    [EmailInfo]$startEmailInfo;
    ...

    MyClass([EmailInfo] $info)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

But it seems not to find it:

> En C:\xxx\yyyy\myscript.ps1: 64 Carácter: 6
>   +     [EmailInfo]$info;
>   +      ~~~~~~~~~ Cannot find the type [EmailInfo].

The strange thing is that I can create new objects without any problem:

```
$emailInfo = New-Object EmailInfo;
```

So the problem seems to be related to using "EmailInfo" as a type.

Finally, if I add "EmailInfo" to the myscript.ps1, that is, the same file where the class is being used, then I can use it as a type...

So, how can I use a class defined in a different file as a type?

Comment: IMO, you will have to put your `custom class` in a `custom PowerShell Module` and then import it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051103/how-to-export-a-class-in-powershell-v5-module). If you don't have `PoSh` version 5, see [this](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/scripting/scripting-classes/import-powershell-classes-from-modules). See if it helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the `using` keyword, at the **very beginning** of your script :

```
using module .\path\to\your\Module.psm1
```

Path can be relative from your current file.

To prevent caching problem, use `powershell.exe .\script.ps1` to execute it, even in the PoweShell ISE console.

Answer (score 0):

At this time (up to and including PowerShell 7), according to the PowerShell team, this is currently not possible: "[The completion logic and the parser errors arise because the language isn't intended to support the way classes are often used](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/3082#issuecomment-737433519)".